# Автоматичекая запись в MySql по запросу с api

Tags: php, mysql, json, vue.js

Есть такой вопрос. Как сделать что бы автоматически записывались поля в MySql, если данные с api изменились? (backend на php, frontend Vue.js + axios)
Я делаю приложения по футболу, получаю данные с api и записываю в БД. И хочу сделать, если забивает гол команда, данные автоматически записывались в базу. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "автоматически"? Если я правильно понимаю, вы через некое стороннее api периодически запрашиваете данные и затем вносите какие-то изменения в бд. Если вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы это происходило без вашего участия, то просто пишете скрипт на php, который вызывает api и вносит необходимые изменения в БД, если обновились данные. А затем вешаете этот скрипт на cron, чтобы он выполнялся, например, раз в минуту (частота зависит от того, насколько оперативно нужно обновляться).

Comment: @SergeyShitikov а как проверять, изменились данные полученные с api, например, за минуту, или нет?

Comment: @David Amerov повешать триггер на поле таблицы и смотреть до апдейта равны значения или нет

Comment: @DavidAmerov, можно сохранять у себя данные из api (или их часть), и при следующем запросе сравнивать с тем, что хранится у вас. Если отличаются - запускаем некий бизнес-процесс. Хранить можно как данные всех сделанных запросов (что накладно), так и просто результат последнего сделанного запроса.

Comment: @SergeyShitikov ага, я понял, буду пробовать реализовать, большое спасибо

Comment: Есть готовое решение на NodeJS, немного не по теме, но посмотрите: [Метеор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_(%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA))